# Remember me (Check Box) Creds are not displayed after logging out

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Remember me creds are not displayed after logging out, if I do it manually then I can see the creds only issue with the automated browser.Also i am doing page refresh after logging out, because clicking on log out the page will not navigate to the login page untile and unless refreshing page.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.